# Getting Information from the path entered by user

Tags: batch-file

I'm want to develop a service which takes a path of a specific location from user and runs the specified java class file.
Here is some of my code:

```
set /p "myPath=Enter the path of the class file in your computer: "
```

now as i have the path of that class file, how can i cd to that path and execute some command on that file i.e (java SomeFile or may be i need to compile some .java file --> javac someFile.java)

I know that doing this --> cd D: in batch file changes the working directory to D:/ but how can i fetch all this information (which drive to CD and where to) from the path input by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are after:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET CURRENT_DIR=%CD%
:Prompt
set /p FilePath=File Path of the class file in your computer:
IF EXIST %FilePath%\NUL (
   ECHO Invalid class file!
   GoTo :Prompt
)
IF NOT EXIST %FilePath% (
   ECHO %FilePath% does not exist!
   GoTo :Prompt
)

for /D %%f in (%FilePath%) DO (
   REM Switch to directory
   ECHO Changing to %%~dpf
   CD /D "%%~dpf"
   ECHO javac %%f
   REM do whatever
)

REM Go back to starting directory
CD /D %CURRENT_DIR%
```

Comment: please explain what this for statement and onward thing do?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed The `FOR` statement is used to break be able to break out the PATH of the specified file (`%%dpf`) and change to that directory (as you requested).  When you use a `FOR` statement on a file or directory, you get access to additional substitution variables.  Take a look at `FOR /?` from the command line for detailed info.